# Webdriver: File Upload

Tags: c#, webdriver

Is there a way to interact with a File Upload box in webdriver?  The form field where the path gets put in is read only so I can't write to that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the value of your input field using JavaScript.  Considering that the id of the field is `fileName` the following example will set the value of the input to the file `C:\temp\file.txt`:

```
String script = "document.getElementById('fileName').value='" + "C:\\\\temp\\\\file.txt" + "';";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

In this example, `driver` is your WebDriver instance.

Please note that you have to use four backslashes (`\`) for Windows-like paths because you are required to pass double back-slashes to the JavaScript so you have to escape both with two additional slashes. The other option is to use a forward slash (e.g. `"C:/tmp/file.txt"`) and that should also work.

Comment: Can this method be made to work for uploading multiple files? Say if you did manually, you select multiple files in the popup file selector. I notice it shows selected files as a double quoted list of filenames separated by a space. If this method works for that, what's the syntax for the JS code?

Comment: This actually will not work, due to security reasons. E.g. most of the  browsers will block this operation! Actually it worked with send_keys method (without executing javascript)

Comment: @OlegTarasenko - I noticed the same thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Comment: What can we do when there is no `<input type="file">` element? I am working with a website where there is a custom button that calls some JS to open a file dialog and then the file is instantly uploaded. There is no element for me to call `document.getElementById` on.

Comment: @aaron-franke looks like you have to identify the script and call it directly in a similar way

Answer (score 21):

You can do this without injecting JavaScript. You just need to get hold of the form field and type into it. Something like (using the Ruby API):

```
driver.find_element(:id, 'upload').send_keys('/foo/bar')
```

Comment: Did you try this? On my app, where the field certainly *looks* like it's read only, it works well.

Comment: anyone try this method for multiple file uploads (selecting multiple files to upload)? I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: C# Version : driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileUpload1")).SendKeys("C:\\foo\\bar");

Comment: @stuartmclark Tried the C# version and the UI acted like it succeeded, but no file was uploaded.

Answer (score 7):

For C#, `SendKeys()` works but you have to use `\` in your file path instead of `/`

For example, the follow works :

```
string filePath = @"drive:\path\filename.filextension";
driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileInput")).SendKeys(filePath);
```

But the following doesn't work :

```
string filePath = "drive:/path/filename.filextension";
driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileInput")).SendKeys(filePath);
```

Comment: This is platform dependent on Linux and macOS it's forward slash. ( / )

Answer (score 3):

The problem I found is the upload dialog hangs the webdriver until closed.
That is, the *element.click* which invokes the upload dialog does not return until that upload dialog is closed.  To be clear, *upload dialog* means an OS-native file selection.

Here is my solution (it's a bit complicated but **shrug** most workarounds for selenium webdriver problems must get complicated).

```
# presumes webdriver has loaded the web page of interest
element_input = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="uploadfile"]')
handle_dialog(element_input, "foobar.txt")

def handle_dialog(element_initiating_dialog, dialog_text_input):
    def _handle_dialog(_element_initiating_dialog):
        _element_initiating_dialog.click() # thread hangs here until upload dialog closes
    t = threading.Thread(target=_handle_dialog, args=[element_initiating_dialog] )
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1) # poor thread synchronization, but good enough

    upload_dialog = webdriver.switch_to_active_element()
    upload_dialog.send_keys(dialog_text_input)
    upload_dialog.send_keys(selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER) # the ENTER key closes the upload dialog, other thread exits
```

Using python 2.7, webdriver 2.25.0, on Ubuntu 12, with firefox.

Comment: Giving this a try in the morning.  I will never understand why .NET developers have a compulsion to mess with file upload dialogs, but I swear they take up more time than any ten other element types combined.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon I tried this but it is not working, the native OS upload window is popped but it does not receive any inputs nor it does receive Enter in last 3 lines of the function. PLease advise

Answer (score 2):

I am in search of 3rd party libraries too,

Unless there is no any other Window Then this works for me :

in C# add reference for System.Windows.Forms

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

string url = "http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/";
string path = @"C:\Users\File_Path";
IWebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
d.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
d.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']")).Click();
hread.Sleep(5000);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(path);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

Comment: Better use the driver.SendKeys and remove the Windows Forms dependency.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i can upload file like solution that write hear but dialog window stuck the process, the driver cant reference to close this window, so i kill him manually:

```
 foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.ToLower().Contains("open"))
               p.Kill();
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use following (ruby API)

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input").send_keys "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg"
```

This is helped me to upload image.