# Automate file uploading in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net, file, image-uploading

I have some images in local folder. I want to grab those images and send them to certain action of the controller without user interactivity. So I do not have to use file up loader to upload files one by one.

I don't know how to automate this task.

I have [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128208/how-to-deal-with-file-uploading-in-test-automation-using-selenium-or-webdriver) this but its using automation tool.

**View Code:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDriverOffence", null, FormMethod.Post, new
{ 
enctype = "multipart/form-data", 
@data_ajax = "false",
id = "ImgForm",
name = "ImgForm",
target = "UploadTarget",
role = "form"
}))
{

   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)
            <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" class="cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
private string AddDriverOffence(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
 // I want to grab image here
}
```

Comment: Nice try, NSA. Can you imagine why it would be a bad idea for random web applications to be able to silently upload arbitrary files?

Comment: It will destroy user privacy.