# C# Selenium IE test upload file with dojo application

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, file-upload, dojo

I'm new to selenium and am trying to write a test case to test a file upload in my localhost dojo application. I've tried using Selenium sendkeys command as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917882/test-upload-file-in-selenium) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823139/selenium-webdriver-upload-file), but it does not assign to input element, nor does it call event for the binded dojo function for my data processing.

Therefore, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33526707/4896260) that allows me to interact with the upload dialog. However, I'm unable to submit the dialog as the enter key closes it versus a mouse click on "Open" which submits it. Below is my code:

```
public IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(MY_DRIVER_LOCATION);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
private void UploadFile(string filename)
{
      driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label.search-btn")).Click();   // Opens the upload file dialog
      var dialogHWnd = FindWindow(null, "Choose File to Upload"); // Title for modal. IE: "Choose File to Upload"
      var setFocus = SetForegroundWindow(dialogHWnd);
      if (setFocus)
      {
          Thread.Sleep(2000);            
          SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TestFile");
          SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
          SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");         // TAB twice to move focus to "Open" button
          SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
          SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");       // <--Error here. Closes dialog instead of submits
      }
  }
```

My html for the file input

```
<label for="tempFile" class="search-btn" style="padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;" data-dojo-attach-point="uploadLabel" >Browse ...</label>
<input id="tempFile" name="file" type="file" style="display:none" />
```

How am I able to submit the upload form dialog with the file I selected for my test case?

*Note: As my machine is managed, I am unable to use programs such as AutoIt to help solve me issue.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not caused by the code, but rather the HTML. I've noticed I was missing my attach point attribute in the input tag. Once it was added, the test ran correctly.

```
<input id="tempFile" name="file" type="file" style="display:none" data-dojo-attach-point="fileNode" />
```