# Canot click button with Python with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, input, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button that brings up a dialogue box to select a file. inspecting the element it looks like its an input rather than a button. Either way I cannot click it with:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("fileupload")
element.click()
```

and

```
browser.find_element_by_id("fileupload").send_keys("\n")
```

Neither of which seem to work.

Here is what I see when I inspect that element on the page:

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> 
    Select and Upload...
  <input id="fileupload" name="upfile" accept=".xml" type="file">
</span>
```

Any assistance help or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on a file input usually triggers a file upload dialog. Since you *cannot control it with `selenium`*, you need to avoid the dialog being opened by sending keys to the `input` instead:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("fileupload").send_keys("path_to_the_file")
```

See also:

- [How to deal with file uploading in test automation using selenium or webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128208/how-to-deal-with-file-uploading-in-test-automation-using-selenium-or-webdriver)
- [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)
- [How to upload file ( picture ) with selenium, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python)