# Selenium Server Standalone sendKeys command

Tags: java, selenium

I want to use selenium-standalone-server to run some tests but when it reaches a `sendKeys` command i get this error: `Unknown command: 'sendKeys'`

this is my full command:

```
sendKeys    | xpath=//input[@type='file'] | abcde
```

as far as i know selenium standalone server uses webdrive which supports sendKeys!!

any body can help?
note that i get this problem both on firefox and google chorme and i'm using selenium-server-2.42.2.jar

I know that `type` works but i want `sendKeys` as it should work either.

Comment: have you tried type instead? and, by standalone server do you mean selenium RC?

Comment: Yes i tried `type` and it works but it does not solve my problem. i need send keys as addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665021/selenium-upload-file-in-google-chrome). no I exactly mean [standalone server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) which is a successor to selenium RC Server

Comment: Is fileupload your problem? Then simply use `type` and `full file path including extension` should work. I don't think `sendKeys` is supported by `RC`

Answer (score 1):

Using `type` with full file path should work as expected.

```
type | xpath=//input[@type='file'] | "c:\\myfile.txt"
```

Comment: this works for firefox bot not for google chrome: and i get this Error: `field can only set to empty string from code`