# Errors In automating Photo Upload using Pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto to automate the process of uploading photo, I use Selenuim to click on a button that pops up a window box to select and upload photo. I use Swapy to get the code for setting up automation, but that codes gives an error of "int took too long to convert" I have tried multiple things but failed

I tried To get it using the class names, titles etc but all failed

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().connect(title=u'Open', class_name='#32770')
window = app.Open
static = window.Static
static.ClickInput()
static.type_keys(Name_of_File)
button = window[u'&Open']
button.Click()
```

I am expecting it to input the name Of file in the windows dialouge box and then click on Open Button to start uploading.

but I get the following error:

```
   return bool(win32functions.IsWindowVisible(handle))
   ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long 
   to convert
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: Upload file in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665021/selenium-upload-file-in-google-chrome)

Comment: @Infern0 I want it done through pywinauto, please check if you can help.

Comment: The same way you click the button with selenium, you can send the path of file you wish to upload. Follow the guide i have provided.

Comment: Which Python version? 2.7/3.x? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Python 3.x and 64 bit

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I can See huge experience on your profile, Please Guide

Comment: It looks like a bug. Thanks for the report (+1 from me). I can suggest to try Python 32-bit so far. Anyway we're going to fix it in next update release 0.6.6 early next year.

Comment: The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/641

Comment: Yeah thanks, for now I have got it working by using multiple things in pywinauto, as I saw answers on your profile it helped. I am making it to try untill a string is written to the file name box and for OPEN key press I am using the enter key press in windows. Using pywinauto Keyboard library.