# uploading image file when no input id is available

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to upload an image but there is no input type available.

The button that opens a OX dialog is:

```
//button[@ng-model='singleFileUpload']
```

The code:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]:

I tried things as described in the following topics but they dont work for me:
[Webdriver: File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300580/webdriver-file-upload)
[c# selenium to browse and upload a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864450/c-sharp-selenium-to-browse-and-upload-a-file)
[How to upload file/ handle window using Selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379358/how-to-upload-file-handle-window-using-selenium-web-driver)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the button archive that, maybe there is a hidden input type=file element, when you click on the button, it will communicate with the hidden input file element. So give a try to find hidden input file element, If find, try to below code:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", hidden_inpyt_file, upload_file_absolute_path);
```