# Upload file to input tag with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, ui-automation

Our application has a page where you can upload a file. The code I wrote will use `SendKeys()` to send the filepath to the `input` tag of the file upload component. However, it's not working on this page.

```
string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\..\..\..\Test Files\" + filename);
uploadInput.Click();
uploadInput.SendKeys(filepath);
```

I've confirmed that the filepath is definitely correct. I've also confirmed that the WebDriver element is definitely correct as well. And, this code **does** work on a totally separate form of our application. My guess is that the way this file upload component is coded must not be compatible with this method.

What other options do I have for uploading a file? Note, controlling the System file explorer is totally out of the question given the environment our tests are run in.

EDIT: I confirmed that the input tag is indeed receiving the file I specify. However the form's custom validation seems to think nothing was uploaded. This might be something I need to resolve with our developers.

Comment: Is it a standard file upload HTML element Or is it a custom file upload ?

Comment: Take a look at this thread, which has a proper solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300580/webdriver-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your path from

```
@"\..\..\..\Test Files\" + filename

to

"\\..\\..\\..\\Test Files\\" + filename
```

OR

```
var path= new System.Uri(""\..\..\..\Test Files\" + filename");
var bakedPath = uri.AbsoluteUri;
```