# Wait for Open File Dialog to Open in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, dialog, functional-testing

I have a Driver that clicks a Browse button on the page which opens a Open File Dialog. As of now, I am doing a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` but is there a way to figure out when the dialog has opened?

```
[Fact]
public void UploadDoc()
{
   UploadButton.Click();

   // How can I wait for the dialog to open instead of doing this?
   Thread.Sleep(2000);

   // Sends keys to open dialog and continues execution
}
```

Comment: If you're talking about the OS-level open file dialog, you can't access that via Selenium.  (Either to know that it's open/closed or to send keys...)

Comment: @pcalkins yes OS level...it's fine I don't need Selenium but would need a better way than just Thread.Sleep

Comment: you might be able to detect because javascript should be blocked.  Look into "blocking dialog detection"... or "blocking operation"... I believe opening file browse should be blocking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webdriver: File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300580/webdriver-file-upload)

Comment: I figured out that there indeed was an input tag that I can sendkeys to